# How to get a value from another file function? python

Tags: python, tkinter

Does anyone can help here?
I have two files called `game.py` and `settings.py`, I just want to get one value from settings to use in game, but I dont know what I am doing wrong.

the value I want it is in the function bbbbb...

```
THIS IS MY SETTINGS
from tkinter import*
import game

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__ (self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def bbbbb(self):
        self.xr = self.ball_numbers.get()
        print("printing...", self.xr)
        return self.xr        

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.ball_numbers = IntVar()

        Label(self,text = "Select how many balls you wish to play:").grid()

        Radiobutton(self, text = "1 Ball", variable = self.ball_numbers, value = 1, command = self.bbbbb).grid ()
        Radiobutton(self, text = "2 Balls", variable = self.ball_numbers, value = 2, command = self.bbbbb).grid ()
        Radiobutton(self, text = "3 Balls", variable = self.ball_numbers, value = 3, command = self.bbbbb).grid ()


settings_window = Tk()
settings_window.title(" THE BOUNCER  -  Settings")
settings_window.geometry("600x600")
app = Application(settings_window)
settings_window.mainloop()
```

I need that value in the class **handling_settings**, in the function **create_ball_numbers**

AND THIS IS MY game.py

```
from livewires import games, color
from tkinter import*
import settings
import random

games.init(screen_width = 735, screen_height = 350, fps = 35)

class Bounce(games.Sprite):
    def update(self):

        if self.right > games.screen.width or self.left < 0: 
            self.dx = -self.dx

        if self.top < 0:
            self.dy = -self.dy

        if self.bottom == 315 and self.overlapping_sprites: 
            self.dy = -self.dy


class Bar_moving(games.Sprite):
    def update(self):   

        self.x = games.mouse.x  
        self.y = 315

class handling_settings():

    self.yr = bbbbb()
    print("printing number from settings  ", self.yr)

    def create_ball_numbers(self):
        print("inside def", self.yr)



def main():

    background = games.load_image("BG.jpg", transparent = False)
    games.screen.background = background

    call = handling_settings()
    call.create_ball_numbers()

    bar_small = games.load_image("bar_small.jpg", transparent = False)
    the_bar_small = Bar_moving(image = bar_small, x = games.mouse.x)

    games.screen.add(the_bar_small)
    games.mouse.is_visible = False
    games.screen.event_grab = True

    games.screen.mainloop()


main()    


I think I am not using on the right way IMPORT on top of the file.... keeping appearing this msg...

File "C:\Users\Bruno\Desktop\DIT\Object Oriented Programming\GAME - Assignment\game.py", line 3, in <module>
    from settings import bbbbb
ImportError: cannot import name bbbbb
```

If I run both files individually... its ok... but when I try to get the value in `bbbbb` function in `settings`, I get stuck...

Comment: Try `self.yr = app.bbbbb()`

Comment: You are trying to use a class function bbbbb() directly, it's allowed. You need to call it with a class object (e.g. app). For that, you can put the variable into builtins and then use it.

Comment: "name 'app' is not defined" doesnot work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First don't do any circular import, in settings.py there is no need to import game module.

As bbbbb is a function of class Application, therefore it cannot be called directly, to call it we need an object of the same class, which is already created as

```
app = Application(settings_window)
```

so, in module game.py, just use app object to call bbbbb()

```
self.yr = settings.app.bbbbb()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a circular import; `settings` imports `game`, which imports `settings`. At that time, neither module is fully done initializing (anything beyond the `import` lines has not yet run).

You don't actually *use* the `game` module in `settings`, so just remove the `import game` line from `settings.py`.

In `game.py`, you imported the `settings` name; `bbbbb` is an attribute on the *`Application`* class in that module. The line:

```
self.yr = bbbbb()
```

will never work here.

You should definitely *not* create a new `Tk()` root window in `settings`, however; you can only ever have *one* main loop in a Tk application. Make `settings` a dialog window triggered by the main application in `game`.

So to get the `bbbbb()` result, you need to instead spawn the settings dialog box, let the user interact with it, and then retrieve the `ball_numbers` setting when the user closes the dialog again.

Comment: I just removed but when I run game now it is saying
"NameError: name 'bbbbb' is not defined"